# How to strip HTML content in flume morphline.conf file using Xquery

Tags: solr, cloudera, flume

We are trying to index the sample xml files to cloudera solr using flume MorphlineSolrSink.

We have created 2 channels ( solrchannel, hdfschannel) and 2 sink (solrsink, hdfssink).
 
We are able to index the document in cloudera solr using this flume and morphline configuration.

Question 1) : We have 2 fields title and content in XML file and we want to strip the HTML content from these 2 fields before sending it to SOLR.
Could you please tell how we can achieve it?

Question 2) : I have to change the Date format of 2 fields, createDate and PublishedDate.
Could you please let me know how to write the logic to change the dateformat of both the fileds at one go.

I am using xQuery to extract the date from my XML files.

---

morphline.conf
https://gist.github.com/jsbonline2006/e04433f9b11cdcafa865#file-morphline-conf

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution for my problem and hence I wanted to share with you guys:

2) After the Xquery command block I wrote following code to convert the date into required format and it worked perfectly fine.

```
  {
    convertTimestamp {
      field : createDate
      inputFormats : ["E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
      inputTimezone : UTC
      outputFormat : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
      outputTimezone : America/Los_Angeles
    }
  }

  {
    convertTimestamp {
      field : publishedDate
      inputFormats : ["E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"]
      inputTimezone : UTC
      outputFormat : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
      outputTimezone : America/Los_Angeles
    }
  }
```

1) For Stripping the HTML tags from title and content we have written a Java code and that we have plugged into our pipeline before send the file content to flume.

Hope this Helps you as well!!!!

Regards,

[Jayesh Bhoyar](http://technical-fundas.blogspot.in/p/technical-profile.html)

http://technical-fundas.blogspot.in/p/technical-profile.html